# virt-sysprep: error: libguestfs error: No such file or directory

Tags: 16.04, networking, ssh, kvm-virtualization

I'm currently running this command

```
virt-sysprep -v -x -c qemu+ssh://user@IPADDRESS/system -d REMOTEVM --hostname REMOTEVM --root-password password:123456 --upload /home/www/interfaces:/etc/network/interfaces
```

but I get this error

```
virt-sysprep -v -x -c qemu+ssh://user@ipaddress/system -d REMOTEVM --hostname REMOTEVM --root-password password:123456 --upload /home/www/interfaces:/etc/network/interfaces
[   0.0] Examining the guest ...
libguestfs: trace: set_verbose true
libguestfs: trace: set_verbose = 0
libguestfs: trace: set_network false
libguestfs: trace: set_network = 0
libguestfs: trace: add_domain "REMOTEVM" "libvirturi:qemu+ssh://user@ipaddress/system" "readonly:false" "allowuuid:true" "readonlydisk:ignore" "discard:besteffort"
libguestfs: opening libvirt handle: URI = qemu+ssh://user@ipaddress/system, auth = default+wrapper, flags = 0
libguestfs: successfully opened libvirt handle: conn = 0x55d71ad4a520
libguestfs: trace: add_libvirt_dom (virDomainPtr)0x55d71ad4e9d0 "readonlydisk:ignore" "discard:besteffort"
libguestfs: original domain XML:\n<domain type='kvm'>\n  <name>REMOTEVM</name>\n  <uuid>c23b6f17-50f4-43e2-9003-463366951382</uuid>\n  <memory unit='KiB'>1048576</memory>\n  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>1048576</currentMemory>\n  <vcpu placement='static'>1</vcpu>\n  <os>\n    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-xenial'>hvm</type>\n    <boot dev='hd'/>\n  </os>\n  <features>\n    <acpi/>\n    <apic/>\n    <vmport state='off'/>\n  </features>\n  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact'>\n    <model fallback='allow'>IvyBridge</model>\n  </cpu>\n  <clock offset='utc'>\n    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>\n    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>\n    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>\n  </clock>\n  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>\n  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>\n  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>\n  <pm>\n    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>\n    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>\n  </pm>\n  <devices>\n    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm-spice</emulator>\n    <disk type='file' device='disk'>\n      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>\n      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/REMOTEVM.qcow2'/>\n      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>\n      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x07' function='0x0'/>\n    </disk>\n    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-ehci1'>\n      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x7'/>\n    </controller>\n    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci1'>\n      <master startport='0'/>\n      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>\n    </controller>\n    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci2'>\n      <master startport='2'/>\n      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x1'/>\n    </controller>\n    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci3'>\n      <master startport='4'/>\n      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x2'/>\n    </controller>\n    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'/>\n    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>\n      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>\n    </controller>\n    <interface type='bridge'>\n      <mac address='52:54:00:83:b3:b0'/>\n      <source bridge='br0'/>\n      <model type='virtio'/>\n      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>\n    </interface>\n    <serial type='pty'>\n      <target port='0'/>\n    </serial>\n    <console type='pty'>\n      <target type='serial' port='0'/>\n    </console>\n    <channel type='spicevmc'>\n      <target type='virtio' name='com.redhat.spice.0'/>\n      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/>\n    </channel>\n    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'/>\n    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>\n    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>\n    <graphics type='spice' autoport='yes'/>\n    <sound model='ich6'>\n      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>\n    </sound>\n    <video>\n      <model type='qxl' ram='65536' vram='65536' vgamem='16384' heads='1'/>\n      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>\n    </video>\n    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>\n    </redirdev>\n    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>\n    </redirdev>\n    <memballoon model='virtio'>\n      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x08' function='0x0'/>\n    </memballoon>\n  </devices>\n</domain>\n
libguestfs: trace: clear_backend_setting "internal_libvirt_norelabel_disks"
libguestfs: trace: clear_backend_setting = 0
libguestfs: disk[0]: filename: /var/lib/libvirt/images/REMOTEVM.qcow2
libguestfs: trace: add_drive "/var/lib/libvirt/images/REMOTEVM.qcow2" "readonly:false" "format:qcow2" "discard:besteffort"
libguestfs: trace: add_drive = -1 (error)
libguestfs: trace: add_libvirt_dom = -1 (error)
libguestfs: trace: add_domain = -1 (error)
virt-sysprep: error: libguestfs error: 
/var/lib/libvirt/images/REMOTEVM.qcow2: No such file or directory
libguestfs: trace: close
libguestfs: closing guestfs handle 0x55d71ad48a00 (state 0)
```

But if I ssh into the remote machine and run the command without the `-c qemu+ssh://user@IPADDRESS/system` it works

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this can't be fixed.  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1596963

> Unfortunately libvirt doesn't provide a way for us to access disks
>   remotely, so if you connect to a remote libvirt it still tries to load
>   the disk as if it was a local file.
>
> This is basically a design problem with libvirt, try for example
>   simply doing: virsh -c qemu+ssh://user@ipaddress/system dumpxml
>   REMOTEVM and look at the disk paths returned.  (It's actually a bit
>   worse than that because there's no way for us to detect if the libvirt
>   connection is local or remote, so eg. @localhost would work).
>
> I'm afraid if you want to sysprep a remote disk you're going to have
>   to find a way to mount the filesystem with the disk locally (eg. share
>   /var/lib/libvirt/images over NFS) or find another way to export the
>   filesystem (eg. NBD) or just run virt-sysprep on the remote box
>   instead.